# Dedicated Nodes in Elasticsearch for Special Client?

Tags: elasticsearch

In our application we have an elasticsearch cluster that is shared for all of our clients.

The types of requests made against this cluster are computationally intense and may take minutes to complete. Because of the type of data in the cluster, the types of requests we get, and the irregularity at which they are used, we can't predict when these requests will be made or do any caching before hand. If multiple clients make requests at the same time, they will experience slower response speeds than normal.

For most clients this isn't an issue. Their data isn't large enough to make a noticeable difference (3s -> 10s occasionally isn't a big deal). But for larger clients, the time difference may be minutes and is very noticeable.

What we'd like, above all else, is consistency- even if these operations were slower on average. To do that, we'd like to give these special clients dedicated nodes, while all other clients use the shared nodes. At a first glance, it seems the only way to do that is to create a dedicated cluster.

[image: dedicated-clusters]

But this adds overhead in any application that interfaces with elasticsearch to first do a lookup for the cluster to route to. Ideally, we'd be able to create dedicated nodes within the cluster. This way, the application doesn't need to be aware of cluster routing, and the index configuration can be shared between these "virtual clusters".

[image: dedicated nodes]

Each document has a client id, which we can use to distribute across nodes using `_routing`. But this has its own problems. Firstly, this doesn't allow us to create a generic default cluster. Secondly, this may mean the dedicated nodes share client data with other clients- the goal is to get consistent speeds by removing node resource contention. And finally, this doesn't allow us to allocate multiple nodes for a given route.

Is there a way to create a routing rule that nodes can be added to explicitly. e.g. I want to add 3 nodes to routing key 582123.

Is there a way to create a default routing rule for nodes that don't match existing routes? If not we could always have an explicit default route. We'll still need to do a route lookup application side but it would still reduce complexity in a multi-cluster scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of elasticsearch you are using and the setup of your indices, you could use [per-index allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html). Basically you give a node an attribute and then you specify on index level settings where that index (more accurately, its shards) should end up. As you will read in the documentation, you need to make sure that other constraints are not being violated e.g.

> Shards are only relocated if it is possible to do so without breaking another routing constraint, such as never allocating a primary and replica shard on the same node.

This means that you need to have different indices though.